# updateoptions in firebase recyclerview inside scrollview not working

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

i have created firebase recyclerview inside nestedscrollview in fragment.it works well.but when i use updateoptions in firebase recyclerview,the recyclerview not working.
I dont know how to resolve this problem.

initially the fragment created it loaded with items from firebase.the recyclerview not work when i click the button to updateoptions

this is my firebaserecyclerview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fragment_bg"
   >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:text="Hi, Aashik"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
        android:textSize="25dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"

        android:text="Welcome Back"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"

        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
        android:text="Category"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
        android:text="Products"
        android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/productsRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="100dp"
            android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layoutanimation"
        />

    </LinearLayout>



</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

and the code is

```
productsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("products");

recyclerView = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.productsRecyclerView);
btn= (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.btn);

 layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Products> options=
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Products>()
                        .setQuery(productsRef, Products.class)
                        .build();

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Products, ProductViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ProductViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull final Products model) {



                   holder.productNameTv.setText(model.getName());
                   Picasso.get().load(model.getImageurl()).fit().into(holder.productImageIv);

                   holder.cardcontainer.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.cardviewanimation));


                   holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View view) {
                           Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ProductDetailsActivity.class);
                           intent.putExtra("imageurl",model.getImageurl());
                           intent.putExtra("name",model.getName());
                           intent.putExtra("desc",model.getDesc());
                           intent.putExtra("mrp",model.getMrp());
                           intent.putExtra("availability",model.getAvailability());
                           intent.putExtra("pid",model.getPid());
                           startActivity(intent);
                       }
                   });


            }


            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_items_layout, parent, false);
                ProductViewHolder holder = new ProductViewHolder(view);
                return holder;
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Query query = productsRef.orderByChild("category").equalTo(catName);

               FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Products> newOptions=
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Products>()
                        .setQuery(query, Products.class)
                        .build();
        adapter.updateOptions(newOptions);
       
);
```

recylerview layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"


    android:id="@+id/cardcontainer"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >


       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/productImageIv"
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_topsym"
           android:layout_margin="10dp"
           >

       </ImageView>
           <RelativeLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               >
               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/productNameTv"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:textSize="20sp"
                   android:text="@string/welcome"
                   android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                   android:fontFamily="@font/arimo_bold"
                   android:padding="20dp">
               </TextView>


           </RelativeLayout>
       </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use swipe to refresh component or use `notifiedDatasetChanged()` in your adapter